# Communication with AWS Token Vending Machine using DynamoDB or any other service

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am new to Amazon AWS and I am trying to setup DynamoDB for my android application.

I have deployed Anonymous TVM on Elastic Beanstalk using:
http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990

When I am accessing mytvm.elasticbeanstalk.com through web browser I am able to load the page saying the TVM is running on Anonymous registration.

1. I am having difficulty understanding how the TVMUser created in IAM is linked to the elasticbeanstalk.

I started working with TVM by cpoying the src of tvm into my android application and doing similar procedure as shown in aws examples.

1. I can't fully figure out whether my TVM is functioning properly with the Android app. I have tried running the examples of awssdk. But the Userprefrences application doesn't create the table when I hit the table or does nothing on my DynamoDB(I see it through the aws ddb console). I try seeing the logcat, but I get the no error.
2. In my application I get a NullPointerException at putItem() at the piece of code below:

   ```
   AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = HomeActivity.clientManager.ddb();

   try{

      HashMap< String, AttributeValue > item = new HashMap< String, AttributeValue >();

       AttributeValue email = new AttributeValue(testEmail);
       item.put("email", email);
       //email and jot are strings and they are fine when printed in Log.
       AttributeValue atrjot = new AttributeValue().withS(jot);
       item.put("jot", atrjot);
       PutItemRequest request = new PutItemRequest().withTableName(PropertyLoader.getInstance().getTableName()).withItem(item);
       ddb.putItem(request);
       Log.e("insertJot", "Succeffull!");
   }catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
       Log.e("insertJot", "error");
       HomeActivity.clientManager
       .wipeCredentialsOnAuthError(ex);
   }
   ```

Two items in the logcat I feel could give some lead are :

> 04-12 11:39:00.577: I/TokenVendingMachineService(1161): Sending Request : [http://mytvm.elasticbeanstalk.com/registerdevice?uid=e3f2a3dbe19a8b99cc9732a8044ccb08&key=258bec0be21ca04f2bf2464a2c0ae151]

and

> 04-12 11:39:00.637: W/AmazonTVMClient(1161): Request to Token Vending Machine failed with Code: [0] Message: [null]

In addition I get the following AndroidRuntime error:

> 04-12 11:39:00.777: D/AndroidRuntime(1161): Shutting down VM
>   04-12 11:39:00.777: W/dalvikvm(1161): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>   04-12 11:39:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-12 11:39:00.797: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): java.lang.NullPointerException

full logcat can be seen here:
http://pastebin.com/u2eyh2ME

I've been stuck with this issue for a long time and cant find proper documentation or help anywhere else, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that `PropertyLoader.getInstance().getTableName()` is returning a null pointer - the rest of the method call shouldn't be throwing the exception

Comment: Thanks Zim-Zam, I suspected it and printed the string, I am able to get the tablename ans its not the problem. I feel the problem is with creating AmazonTVM Client where I am unable to sendRequest() to the TVMService.

Comment: [This article](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) explains the IAM User's role in TVM. In order to debug your issue, it's probably a good idea to go to the Management Console for the AWS ElasticBeanstalk, and use 'Logs' > 'Snapshot Logs'. It may give you some helpful information.